# Create connection between SQL Server 2008 R2 and Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, rest, xamarin

Good morning,
I'm testing the free version of Xamarin Studio and I want to connect my Android application to my database. As I write in the title I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I read that the best solution is to use a web service. The problem is that is the first time that I create a web service and I don't know how to do all this procedure. Someone can guide me? I found this link (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api). So I can create this web service using Visual Studio and then I can create the app using Xamarin Studio (right?). Can I try to do this also using the free version? Because I saw that System.Data.SqlLite is available only for higher version (from Business). Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a way to do it. Create a WebAPI service and then access it from Xamarin using a REST client, i.e. [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http). You won't be needing SQLite for this, just a client that sends and receives JSON data (or any other format if you choose so). [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) is a sample HttpClient use. You would also need Json (de)serializer, i.e. [Json.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). Here is another [complete example](http://johnnycode.com/2012/02/23/consuming-your-own-asp-net-web-api-rest-service/).

Comment: Hi Miha, thanks for your answer. I created a WEB API using Visual Studio and I add some code in my application but I received an error. This is part of the code 
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"http://localhost:54276/api/values"));
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "GET";
**using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)**
{ if ...
The error  is ConnectFailure (Network is unreachable) but I set Internet and Network State as permission. Do you think that is because the free version or it's my error?
Thanks